# Use Reveal.js for a WordPress Site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, presentation, reveal.js

I want to install [`reveal.js`](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/) for my website which is based on a WordPress theme. I searched for a WordPress plugin that allows me to use `reveal.js` and I did not find any. I also did not find any instructions to manually install this awesome presentation maker. Can I install `reveal.js` by for example copying its content to the directory of the webpage and then paste the html code of the presentation into a Raw html Element and get the presentation to work? What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-present/  but you can also create a custom page template and link the script files,

Comment: I installed it but I could not find any instructions how I can use this plugin and create a `reveal.js` presentation.

Comment: Apparently, `wp-present` plugin has not been tested with my current version of WordPress, according to the plugin description. Because of this, I don't see the correct settings, boxes, and elements, when I try to create a presentation. It only allows me to create a blog with a simple formatted text.

Comment: well then create the custom template and link the files, or have a look at the errors in the plugin.

Comment: Would you share how this template should be made? Thank you.

Comment: just create a template in your theme https://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates and then code like a html page. Try it and then if you get stuck you can ask for help.